# directing airplay ouput to secondary display

Tags: ios, graphics, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am using IMX6 Saberauto board on Linux OS. I have 2 displays primary is HDMI and secondary is LVDS. I want to run 2 applications.

One QT on primary display, which I am able to do. Second application is airplay application I want this applicaiton to run on seondary display ie /dev/fb2. But I am not able to do.

It is coming on primary display only. Please let me know the command to direct airplay output to /dev/fb2

Comment: does anyone have any suggestion plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer since I am using VPU decoder it has options as to where it can direct the decoded output.FOllowing is the command ./mxc_vpu_test.out -D "-i filename -f 2 -x 18", here -x refers to display and 18 corresponds to video 18 which is mapped to LVDS.And -f refers to the decoder and it is set to 2 which is VPU decoder.